# Draggable card that snaps to grid in React

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, css-grid

React newbie here.

I am looking for a way to add drag and drop functionality to my website. The goal is to move cards in a grid (I am currently using tailwind css to handle the grid). I found a few libraries that enable drag and drop but none that would:

- work in a grid, i.e. in 2D
- snap the cards to the grid
- reorganize the cards when one is moved (to prevent overlapping)

I tried using [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) but it seems to only be suitable for lists (i.e. 1D). I also tried [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/) but I couldn't make it work either, I don't think it is meant to be used in a grid.

I found some libraries that do exactly what I want in angular (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dragdrop-grid) and in vue (https://codesandbox.io/s/j4vn761455), but I can't seem to find react equivalents.

Would you know a react library I could use?

Thanks

Comment: try https://sortablejs.github.io/react-sortablejs/

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!